# How can I have a button to minimize the form and another to exit without writing the same code in every form?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I made a borderless form so I created my own exit and minimize buttons. It works, but I wanted to know if there's a way to avoid having to write what each button does in each form. I've tried to create a module but I never learnt how to use that, and I don't know how to make it work, as I can't use "me.Close" and those things... anyone can help me?

Comment: Try to inherit your child from from your main form

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with **Inheritance**

Inheriting a winForm In Vb.Net

```
Public Class CustomerEditForm
Inherits VBInheritanceSample.DataEntryBaseForm
```

Inheriting a winForm In C#

```
public class CustomerEditForm :
CSInheritanceSample.DataEntryBaseForm
```

Now, for a complete example similar to your case, please visit this tutorial called: [Understanding Visual Inheritance in .NET](http://www.codemag.com/Article/0102021).

In this tutorial you will learn to create a winForm with buttons and events. After that, it shows you how to inherit to another winForms.

Well, this is just one way, I think people can tell you another good idea.

Comment: It is the same idea my friend: "Inheritance". Well that's the way that I would follow. At the end I wrote "is just one way, I think people can tell you another good idea". You can suggest another code :)

Comment: Just "Inherit" the Button itself and create a control. Add the click event and handle it from there. Drag and drop the newly inherited button onto the form. 2 options, either create a property that tells the button what to do when clicked or handle it in the class...

Comment: Post it as an answer, no in the comments section :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the me to sender."so if you call it on form2 , its Me.Close for form2"

In form1 you add the code for exit and minimized in a public sub.

```
Public Sub MinimizeForm(sender As Object)
    sender.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
End Sub

Public Sub ExitForm(sender As Object)
    sender.Close()
End Sub
```

From form1 you call it like this :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.MinimizeForm(Me)
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Me.ExitForm(Me)
End Sub
```

Then from form2 and all the other forms you call it like this :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form1.MinimizeForm(Me)
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Form1.ExitForm(Me)
End Sub
```